# What is the difference between binary and utf8?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, buffer

[This](https://github.com/wayfind/is-utf8) node library checks whether a buffer is binary or utf8, but the contents of the test files ([ansi.txt](https://github.com/wayfind/is-utf8/blob/master/ansi.txt), [utf8.txt](https://github.com/wayfind/is-utf8/blob/master/utf8.txt)) look exactly the same and I couldn't find any clear explanations of the differences.

What exactly is the difference between binary and utf8?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Sleafar Not a mention of what binary is in that article..

Comment: Usually binary is used as opposite of text data. In your context it seems to mean "not UTF8". If you want get philosophical, you could say all data processed by a computer is binary. It simply depends on the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Binary" is just a general term for data that is not human-readable text. It has nothing to do with encoding. Also, there are plenty of other ways to encode text than UTF-8, so binary and UTF-8 are not the only possible types of data.

The documentation says that `isUtf8` checks whether it is encoded in UTF-8 or not. If it returns true, you know that the file is encoded in UTF-8. However if it returns false, you can **not** conclude that the file contains binary data, because it could also be encoded in UTF-16, ANSI, or other text encoding formats that are not considered binary.

According to the source code, the function reads the whole file and checks for UTF-8 encoded characters outside of the ASCII range. It looks like it will return true if there are only ASCII characters in the file, because the file would be the same in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Also there is no line 13 in utf8.txt, it only contains 7 lines for me.

Comment: *"Not UTF-8" is not the same as "binary"* I don't understand, so `utf8 === binary`? The double negative makes it a little difficult to understand. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like my Browser forwarded me to something irrelevant instead of the actual files. The files are identical, I rephrased my answer. To be clear: utf8 does not equal binary.

Comment: The files are not identical. The UTF8 version is bigger. Press the "Raw" button, then you will see a difference.

Comment: Okay, looks like I can't think clear at the moment. I thought I checked both file hashes, but of course you are right.